# Project with path could not be found in root project

Tags: gradle

I got the following project structure

```
project
-- build.gradle
-- gradle
  | -- java.gradle
  | -- artifacts.gradle
```

In my root build.gradle I wrote

```
apply from: 'gradle/artifacts.gradle'
```

In my artifacts.gradle I build an ear and wanted to set the war task (also in `artifacts.gradle`) as a deploy dependency with

```
project(path: ':myWar', configuration: 'myWar')
```

Now gradle throws me the error `Project with path <path> could not be found in root project <project>.`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In

> project(path: ':myWar', configuration: 'myWar')

The `:myWar` path must match some of the projects declared in

`/settings.gradle`

Based on information you provided it seems you have only root project?

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
I only have the root Project and I dont want the gradle folder to be a sub project.

I use the gradle dir only to not have a single huge build.gradle (I have more .gradle scripts in the gradle dir).

I already tried to declare the gradle dir as a sub project but then I would need to overwrite the projectDir, because all paths are relative to the root projectDir. And I didn't find a way to overwrite the projectDir of sub projects.

Comment: The answer to your question why you are getting "Project with path could not be found in root project" is that, as I wrote, by `path: ':myWar'` you are referencing to **the project** that you do not use.

Comment: You can add your war to deploy configuration as follows (in case your task is named myWar)

`deploy myWar.archivePath`

Comment: Since the answer answers your question please accept it so the others can know it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

##### Options

1. Check if the subproject has a `settings.gradle` in it (Gradle may define it as the root project)
2. Delete the `.gradle` folder in your project's root folder and resync gradle in your IDE
3. Check if the project name in `settings.gradle` and `build.gradle` matches with the folder name, otherwise change the project or directory name

```scala
include('subproject')
project(':subproject').projectDir = file('./path_to_/subproject')
```

4. Consider your project's structure: by default `:subproject` must be a subfolder of the rootProject named **subproject** from where the `settings.gradle` file resides.